# Legendre associated functions

Tags: special-functions

From this

$$P^m_n(x)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2^nn!}(1-x^2)^{m/2}\displaystyle\frac{d^{n+m}}{dx^{n+m}}(x^2-1)^n$$

I should derive that

$$P^{-m}_n(x)=(-1)^n\displaystyle\frac{(n-m)!}{(n+m)!}P_m^n(x)$$

Using the Leibniz's formula to $(x^2-1)^n=(x-1)^n(x+1)^n$

But I get lost adding terms in the Leibniz expansion...I appreciate any help to get this result.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equate the coefficients of equal powers on the left and right hand side of
$$
    \frac{d^{n-m}}{dx^{n-m}} (x^2-1)^{n} = c_{nm} (1-x^2)^m \frac{d^{n+m}}{dx^{n+m}}(x^2-1)^{n}, 
$$
then it follows that the proportionality constant is
$$
    c_{nm} = (-1)^m \frac{(n-m)!}{(n+m)!} , 
$$
so that
$$
    P^{-m}_n(x) = (-1)^m \frac{(n-m)!}{(n+m)!} P^{m}_n(x). 
$$

Comment: Why this proportionality holds?

Comment: Since the associated Legendre equation is invariant under the substitution $m → −m$, the equations for $P_n^{±m}$ are proportional.

To obtain the proportionality constant we consider
$$
    (1-x^2)^{-m/2} \frac{d^{n-m}}{dx^{n-m}} (x^2-1)^{\ell} = c_{nm} (1-x^2)^{m/2} \frac{d^{n+m}}{dx^{n+m}}(x^2-1)^{n},\qquad 0 \le m \le n, 
$$
and we bring the factor $(1−x²)^{−m/2}$ to the other side; and then, equate...

Comment: Amazing way to get the result! 
But I don't understand yet why the invariance implies the proporcionality. But assuming it holds, I get the result. Thanks!